# Add up all of the columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, count

I am creating a social network, I need to show the user how many people they follow and how many people follow them(followers and following). I want to add up the values in the `user_to` and `user_from` where the current user logged in is the person who followed someone or received a follow.

I am using this code below:

```
$user_follow_query = $con->prepare('SELECT SUM(user_to) FROM following WHERE user_to = ?');
$user_follow_query->bind_param("s", $username);
$user_follow_query->execute();
$user_follow_query->bind_result($followers);    
$user_follow_query_result = $user_follow_query->get_result();

while ($row = $user_follow_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $followers = $row['user_to'];
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: user_to in C:\wamp64\www\theshow\profile.php on line 38
```

On this line:

```
$followers = $row['user_to'];
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you need to alias the column returned by the query so you can then access it it in the outer query.

So something like:

```
SELECT SUM(user_to) sum_user_to FROM following WHERE user_to = ?
```

Lets you then access the resulting column with `$row['sum_user_to']`.

But I also highly doubt that your query does what you want. If you want to count the followers, then that's the number of rows that satisfy the `WHERE` condition, so you want `COUNT(*)` rather than a `SUM()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) no_followers FROM following WHERE user_to = ?
```

If you want both followers and followees, as explained in your question, then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) no_relations
FROM following 
WHERE ? in (user_to, user_from)
```